# Can you walk across the Queensboro bridge to Roosevelt Island?

Tags: new-york-city

So I know that you can walk over the Queensboro Bridge, but can you stop off at Roosevelt Island? I know that there is also a Roosevelt Island Bridge, but I want to know specifically about the Queensboro Bridge.

Comment: It's only for Spiderman at the moment.  The rest have to wait until the elevator is restored to service again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope, not unless you have a time machine.  There used to be an elevator, but it doesn't exist anymore.  You can walk over the island, though, then take the subway back to the island.

More info: http://rioc.ny.gov/transportation.htm

Comment: +1, can you add any info about when the elevator will be restored?

Comment: There have been attempts by the residents of Roosevelt Island to petition the city for pedestrian access, but the city hasn't done anything other than smile and nod.  I doubt the elevator will be restored, but another means of pedestrian access may eventually exist.

Comment: If you are in Manhattan, you can walk over the QB bridge and then up to the bridge that connects Roosevelt Island with Queens, and walk over that.  If you are in Queens, you can skip the first part, of course.

Comment: @TimKennedy any other form of pedestrian access would probably be far more impractical than an elevator.  It seems unlikely.

Comment: @GayotFow: Asking when the elevator will be restored makes it sounds like it's temporarily out of service for repairs.  But the link in the answer seems to say that the elevator was demolished in 1970.

Comment: @NateEldredge, yes. I'm in the people who would like to see it working again.  Spiderman notwithstanding...